# How can I get & keep an unauthorized user out of my network?

Tags: malware, identity, system-compromise

I have replaced hardware, equipment, and passwords. I think they are in Yahoo, Microsoft, phone, and laptop. I have changed all with no success. They use my identity as the temporary ID from Microsoft domain mgmt.. appears my location, IP, and ID. Can see they use a different firewall and usually through XBox bar which I can't uninstall. They continuously change settings and enable microphone etc.

Any suggestions? The only thing I can't lose is my business name. I think there are startup settings prohibiting me from fixing a lot of it. They also defer my help files and certain documentation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Security SE. Did someone else than you witnessed these suspicious events?

Comment: It is difficult to determine what is going on simply by the effects in other things that you have observed. This is like asking "someone crashed my car, how did they break in?"

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the proofing! Yes it has been witnessed by several others. I'm not just imagining it. I can limit their access a little bit by resetting when I realize they are back in my accounts. I'm not sure if it is from a tech scam last year or my landlords kids. Either way it's violating and time consuming. I have reached out to support; however, I have been unable to resolve the issue. I am registered as a workspace not with my custom domain. This might be the problem with some issues but I am not the global admin. Someone else is assigning roles and permissions via ID from Microsoft.